# Change keras regularizer during training / dynamic regularization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am looking for a proper way to implement a dynamic regularization of weights for a layer during the training. As an example after 10 calls I want to replace the L2 regularization with the L1 regularization only for specific weights of MyLayer. The following shows an example of the layer implementation:

```
class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(...)
        some code
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.L2() # this regularization should be changed after some steps
        self.my_weights = self.add_weight(name='myweights', shape=(self.input_dim, ),
                    initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(1,),
                    regularizer= self.regularizer, trainable=True)
        self.counter = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32)
        ...
    def call(self, inputs):
        ... do some processing ...
        # for the following code i look for a proper implementation
        if self.counter > 10:
            self.regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.L1()
        tf.keras.backend.update(self.counter,self.counter+1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could form your problem not as change the regularizer from [L1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/L1)->[L2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/L2), but form it as change the [L1L2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/L1L2) regularizer's parameters, so we can in principle change the regularizer

And we can't change the hyperparameters after compile the model (you can if you [custom the training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough)), because **the hyperparameters are built-in to the training function when you compile**

We want modify hyperparameters during training, and the way to do it is **use backend variables in the training function and update those variables during training**

So we could define the following custom regularizer:

```
class L1L2_m(Regularizer):
    """Regularizer for L1 and L2 regularization.
    # Arguments
        l1: Float; L1 regularization factor.
        l2: Float; L2 regularization factor.
    """

    def __init__(self, l1=0.0, l2=0.01):
        with K.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
            self.l1 = K.variable(l1,name='l1')
            self.l2 = K.variable(l2,name='l2')
            self.val_l1 = l1
            self.val_l2 = l2
            
    def set_l1_l2(self,l1,l2):
        K.set_value(self.l1,l1)
        K.set_value(self.l2,l2)
        self.val_l1 = l1
        self.val_l2 = l2

    def __call__(self, x):
        regularization = 0.
        if self.val_l1 > 0.:
            regularization += K.sum(self.l1 * K.abs(x))
        if self.val_l2 > 0.:
            regularization += K.sum(self.l2 * K.square(x))
        return regularization

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'l1': float(K.get_value(self.l1)),
                  'l2': float(K.get_value(self.l2))}
        return config
```

Add your custom object so that when you want to export your model you won't have any issue in reloading it:

```
from keras.utils.generic_utils import get_custom_objects
get_custom_objects().update({ L1L2_m.__name__: L1L2_m })
```

Update your variable using the custom object set_l1_l2 method:

```
class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(...)
        some code
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.regularizer = L1L2_m() # this regularization should be changed after some steps
        self.my_weights = self.add_weight(name='myweights', shape=(self.input_dim, ),
                    initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(1,),
                    regularizer= self.regularizer, trainable=True)
        self.counter = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int32)
        ...
    def call(self, inputs):
        ... do some processing ...
        # for the following code i look for a proper implementation
        if self.counter == 10:
            self.regularizer.set_l1_l2(0.01,0.)
        tf.keras.backend.update(self.counter,self.counter+1)
```

Reference:

[How to change regularization parameters during training?](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4813)

Comment: Not a perfect answer...!